# How to use JSON as config file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm looking for a way where I can use a JSON as a config file,

My JSON config file looks like :

```js
{
'Lang' : 'EN',
'URL' : '/over/dose/app'
}
```

and I want to get the URL and Lang in the html file using javascript or jQuery.
I don't wanna use an asynchronous method like `$.getJson`.

I want to get the Url and language from JSON file something like :

```
var url = myjson.URL;
```

so I can use the var later in so many different functions.

Comment: Well first you have to have JSON. What you posted isn't JSON.

Comment: In the browser or in the server?

Comment: in Server the JSON is on the same domain

Comment: For future reference, while a proposal at the moment, it's likely you'll be able to [`await`](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) asynchronous actions without giving up the non-blocking behavior.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't want to use an asynchronous call you can always assign a variable to the config object and put the file in the `src` of a script tag

```
var appConfig={
    'Lang' : 'EN',
    'URL' : '/over/dose/app'
}
```

.

```
<script src="/path/to/config.js"></script>
<script> alert(appConfig.URL);</script>
```

Advantage is immediate loading. Possible disadvantage is it isn't a json file any more, it is regular javascript file in case you are writing to it from server code.

Of course this also creates a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
var cfg = {};
$.ajax({
  url: myUrl,
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    cfg = JSON.parse(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do Not Use `async: false`. It is a terrible practice and is already being deprecated by browser vendors and by jQuery

Comment: Note that `async: false` is deprecated in 1.8+ and is likely to be removed in a future release.

Comment: interesting. something new to make it synch?

Comment: @Mephiztopheles no, but using it has been discouraged for years since it blocks the UI

Comment: @Mephiztopheles No. Synchronous requests are generally considered detrimental to the user experience as they lock up the page while the request processes. The native XMLHttpRequest now only supports them when a `timeout` is specified.

Comment: so there will be no ways to wait for something loaded, got from server after document ready?

Comment: successive, consecutively... i want to have ajax calls and when the ajax call is finished, all other actions can ride along... i don't know if im getting it right, but should't `async: false` do this?